# Sending POST parameters from apiary

Tags: django, apiary.io

I have created a REST API using Django.  I'm making a POST request with some parameters

```
user_id="5453ab249b0dbb3b76000009"
user_type="instrcutor"
```

In apiary blueprint , i'm sending these as a part of request body like:

```
+ Request (application/json)

    + Body        

            {
                "user_id": "5453ab249b0dbb3b76000009",
                "user_type": "instructor"
            }
```

But in my Django view , request.POST is coming like:

```
{u'{\n        "user_id": "5453ab249b0dbb3b76000009",\n        "user_type": "instructor"\n}': [u'']}
```

instead of

```
{u'user_id': [u'5453ab249b0dbb3b76000009'], u'user_type': [u'instructor']}
```

How can i send the post data correctly ?

**EDIT**

Here is the solution:

```
+ Request (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

    user_id=5453ab249b0dbb3b76000009&user_type=instructor
```

Answer (score 0):

If apiary is sending json (you wrote it in body block), you should look and parse `request.body` instead of `request.POST`

Comment: that would be overhead.